# ¿Como puedo insertar un objeto de una clase a un atributo de tipo array de otra clase que utiliza templates?

Tags: c++, poo, template-strings

Debo crear una clase Lista (una lista estatica) que almacene objetos de otra clase que es Libro, en la clase libro tiene solo sus atributos, metodos y un metodo toString...

Me da este error:

> no matchfor 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Libro' and 'int')

Este es el archivo Lsta.h

```
template<class T>
class Lista
{
private:
    T libro[N];
    int libroCont;
public:
    Lista();
    void inserta(T libro);
    void inserta(T libro, int pos);
};
template<class T>
Lista<T>::Lista()
{
    libroCont = 0;
}
template<class T>
void Lista<T>::inserta(T libro)
{
    inserta(libro, libroCont);
}
template<class T>
void Lista<T>::inserta(T libro, int pos)
{
    if (libroCont==N)
        return;
    libro[pos++]=libro;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>
void Lista<T>::inserta(T libro, int pos)
//                       ~~~~~ variable local libro
{
    if (libroCont==N)
        return;
    libro[pos++]=libro; // libro[] = libro ??
}
```

Hay que tener cuidado con los nombres de las variables. Dos variables pueden llamarse exactamente igual siempre y cuando su ámbito no sea exactamente el mismo. En tu caso tienes una variable miembro y una variable local que se llaman igual.

En este escenario, para acceder a la variable miembro es imprescindible usar `this`:

```
this->libro[pos++] = libro;
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Libro' and 'int')

> no se encontró coincidencia para 'operator[]' (los tipos de los operandos son 'Libro' e 'int')

Básicamente te está diciendo que has usado el operador de indizado (los corchetes `[` y `]`) sobre un objeto que no lo tiene definido.

El único sitio de tu código en que usas el operador de indizado es en la última línea de la función `Lista::inserta`:

```
template<class T>
void Lista<T>::inserta(T libro, int pos)
{
    if (libroCont==N)
        return;
    libro[pos++]=libro;
}
```

El código está confundiendo el argumento `libro` con la variable miembro `Lista::libro` porque tienen el mismo nombre.

Tienen el mismo nombre porque dentro de las funciones miembro, los miembros del objeto no necesitan su jerarquía como parte de su nombre (es decir, `Lista::libro` se llama `libro` dentro de las funciones de `Lista`).

Por otro lado, en la jerarquía de nombres, tienen preferencia los nombres más locales frente a los nombres menos locales, así que dentro de la función `Lista::inserta` el nombre `libro` se refiere al argumento y no a la variable miembro ya que el primero es más local que el segundo.

Para evitar este problema puedes cambiar la notación:

```
template<class T>
class Lista
{
private:
    // Las variables miembro tienen el prefijo 'm_'
    T m_libro[N];
    int m_libroCont;
public:
    Lista();
    // Los argumentos tienen el prefijo 'a_'
    void inserta(T a_libro);
    void inserta(T a_libro, int a_pos);
};

// Se ve claramente qué variables son miembro y cuáles son argumentos.
template<class T>
void Lista<T>::inserta(T a_libro, int a_pos)
{
    if (m_libroCont==N)
        return;
    m_libro[a_pos++]=a_libro;
}
```